# Foreign Key Possibility of Two Models

Tags: python, database, django

Let's say I have two models, `Entry` and `Post`. Simple models, but they share several fields (subject, description, etc... this is hypothetical since I'm still in the design stage). I have another field, Acknowledgement, which is simply an association between an `Entry` or a `Post` and a `Customer`. If it were implemented only for `Entry` relationships, it would look like this:

```
class Acknowledgement(models.Model)

    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

However, I want it to be able to function as a join table for EITHER `Entry` or `Post` and `Customer`, never both. I'm vaguely familiar with generic keys as an option, but I don't know if that's the best route here, since I'd like to restrict the foreign key to one of those two model types. Any ideas on a good approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

The route that i would take is:

Override save() method of the model Acknowledgement , and in save() check if relations are fine or if not, throw an exception.